# Is there any way to specify custom connection parameters to scalikejdbc?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-athena, scalikejdbc

When connecting to AWS Athena, a required parameter is `s3_staging_dir` to specify the output directory of the query. Is there any way to specify this parameter in scalikejdbc? I've tried looking through all of scalikejdbc's docs, but I found nothing of this sort.

Athena doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html
Scalikejdbc doc: http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/configuration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to do it using a custom connection pool factory.

I did manage to connect to Athena, but I couldn't execute any SQL since "prepareStatement" is not implemented in the Athena JDBC driver.

So don't try it, It'll be useless.

Sorry :(